# How to change the histogram bar thickness?

Tags: lightweight-charts

I want to change the bar thickness of the histogram, is there a way to do it, I'm asking because I didn't find it in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible right now, but [there is an issue](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/272) you can subscribe on to get notified when it is done.